# How can I write a udev rule that will apply to a PCI device at boot time?

Tags: linux, centos, udev, pci

I have a PCI device on a CentOS 7.6 system that needs some special configuration to be applied via `setpci` in order for it to operate properly. I would like to create a udev rule that will automatically run a script to apply those settings when the device is detected at boot time.

I created a rule that looks like this:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x1234", ATTR{device}=="0x5678", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'KERNEL=$kernel /usr/sbin/device-pci-setup.sh'"
```

However, I found that the rule doesn't appear to execute at boot time when the device is added. If I change the `ACTION` to `change`, then run `udevadm trigger`, then the rule runs properly and invokes the script; it just doesn't run at boot time (I'm guessing because the PCI device is detected too early and it may not have full filesystem access yet).

[It doesn't look like I'm the first to have this problem, but there was no solution provided here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53157). Is there a way to make this work as desired at boot time?